# Mathematica automatically puts pluses in list

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, data-manipulation

I have a notebook that I have been using quite a while and everything worked perfect up until now. Somehow when evaluating the notebook mathematica puts a plus begin every value in the lists like this:

```
(x1 +, x2 +, x3 +, ... , xn +)
```

Now I can't use the lists anymore for graphical things. Yesterday I did not have this problem yet, and I changed nothing in the code so I don't know where this comes from, I hope any of you have an idea how to solve this.

Comment: What is the `FullForm` of one of these lists?

Comment: maybe you multiplied something by a plus character, `{4, 5, 6} "+"` -> `{4 +, 5 +, 6 +}`